# Installation DVD is not actually bootable

Tags: system-installation, dvd, mate

I’ve been unsuccessful in my attempts (three attempts to date) at creating a bootable DVD using the online iso of **Ubuntu Mate 18.04.3 (Bionic) 32-bit version**, which I downloaded from https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/).

I used two different computers in my attempts at creating a bootable DVD.

First, on a **Windows 7** machine, I downloaded the iso for **Ubuntu Mate 32-bit version** using **uTorrent**, and then I burned that iso to a DVD using the Windows-bundled default disk burner application. When I tried booting a **Lenovo** notebook from the resultant DVD, the boot process got stuck in some kind of endless loop, with code-text scrolling rapidly and endlessly on the screen.
Secondly, using the same computer, the same **Windows** OS, the **Rufus** USB flash-drive-writer, and the same downloaded-iso for **Ubuntu Mate 32-bit version** as before, I burned the iso onto a USB stick, which then I found to be unbootable into the same **Lenovo** notebook. The error message (which I didn’t write down) specified some files that were deemed missing.
Thirdly, and in contrast, I performed an experiment, in which I succeeded in creating a bootable USB stick using the iso of **Lubuntu 32-bit version** (not **Ubuntu Mate 32-bit version**), which I burned to a USB stick using the **Rufus** application. However, I need a bootable DVD for **Ubuntu Mate 32-bit version**.

Next, on an **Lubuntu** machine, I downloaded the online iso for **Ubuntu Mate 32-bit version** again - this time using **Transmission**, and then I burned the new iso onto two DVDs using different disk writers, **Xfburn** and **k3b**. I found both of those resultant DVDs to be unbootable too. I don’t have another available USB stick, otherwise next I might have tried making a bootable USB stick using the **Ubuntu Mate** iso - but anyway I want a bootable DVD.

Comment: Did you validate the checksums of the Mate iso before burning to disk? It's unlikely that you got a corrupted version both times, but not impossible.

Comment: Seems like you *did* make a bootable DVD. At least twice. Your real problem seems to be some issue that is causing those boot errors. Need much more detail to help with those.

Comment: There is a function "check disc for defects" which validates the download & write to install-media was perfect, I'd suggest running that.  Depending on your machine specs this menu item will either be obvious, or require you to press a key for the menu to appear (keyboard in rectangle & person-in-circle appears you hit a key quickly)

Comment: *I don’t have another available USB stick*. You can try [YUMI](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) which is a multiboot creator (if you have windows machine), there are others for linux, like [http://multibootusb.org/](http://multibootusb.org/).

Comment: This maybe is a stupid question, but ¿Do you select in your BIOS to boot from the CD/DVD?

Comment: Generally yes, you need to have CD/DVD as a boot option (or above your hdd/ssd otherwise it'll only boot if you have no hdd/ssd).  On some machines you can hit a fn key to have a question appear asking what to boot (keys vary on BIOS & make, eg. maybe f12, f9 or other key).

Comment: @Arronical. I did not validate the checksums of theMate iso 'manually', because I read in the instructions for creating a bootable DVD that uTorrent, Transmission, etc do that anyway.

Comment: @user535733 I'll provide whatever additional detail I can.

Comment: We need to know accurate and complete error messages. Whatever you saw *before* the error message (flicker, some text, a picture, whatever) is also very helpful. For streaming text, tell us the last couple lines before the stream of text ends, and also tell us about any FAIL messages in the stream. Take a (very clear) video with your phone if it's too hard to describe, but be aware that many helpers here won't click on video links so you might get less help. We must be able to clearly read any text in a video, or it's worthless.

Comment: @Arronical  There does appear to be a difference between the endings of the two sha256sum.       The sha256sum of the downloaded iso is:
4b06c2cb927d2be425e7d3346a92cd94576d45607698ab1e6a5e7ddbafcbc6c0
The sha256sum as stated on source page is: 
4b06c2cb927d2be425e7d3346a92cd94576d45607698ab1e6a5e7ddbafc            That is, there is an additional "bc6c0" at the end of the sha256sum for the downloaded iso.      What does this signify?

Comment: @Arronical. I tried to get the sha256sum for one of the problemDVDs. Here's the text from    Terminal:   $ sha256sum /dev/cdrom
sha256sum: /dev/cdrom: Input/output error

Comment: @guiverc. I haven't suceeded yet in finding the "check disc for defects"  function in Lubuntu. It sounds like a useful utility.

Comment: @guillermo chamorro.   If I understand, your meaning is that one can put several bootable isos on a single USB stick using YUMI (using Windows machines) or using multiboot (using other platforms).  That's really useful.   Can I add another iso to the USB stick on which I have Lubuntu now?     Can I add a bootable iso to any USB stick that has enough free space?        To answer your question, yes, I did set my BIOS to boot from the DVD. On my machine I press the F1 key just after restarting.

Comment: @Hotspur *one can put several bootable isos on a single USB stick*. Yes, that's correct. YUMI can be run in linux with wine, but I didn't have good experiences with that. *Can I add another iso to the USB stick on which I have Lubuntu now*. Mmh, it may be possible, but you would have to edit some files, and that's kinda advanced stuff (I will try it). *Can I add a bootable iso to any USB stick that has enough free space*. Yes, using the multiboot tools you can. (You can even create a multiboot just using the command line, no extra software, but again, that's a bit complicated).

Comment: The lubuntu manual https://manual.lubuntu.me/1/1.3/installation.html shows the first screen; i mean the option below the "start Lubuntu" on the first screen picture (on booting the cd/dvd/thumb-drive).  All desktop Ubuntu's have the function (*I believe*) though as already stated, your machine (bios, uefi..) will control how it appears (as a text screen, graphic logo, or a key needs to be pressed for the menu to appear)  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck is the page from Ubuntu wiki (how it appears varies on release/flavor)